# Create data frame and specify row/column names in a single operation

Tags: r

From an old `R` thread captured in `nabble` the indication is that three separate operations are required to obtain the result described in the title of this post  http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/To-give-column-names-of-a-data-frame-td2249996.html:

```
results <- data.frame(matrix(c(1,2,3,4),nrow=2,ncol=2)) 
rownames(results) <- c("a","b") 
colnames(results) <- c("c","d")
```

Can these be collapsed into a single operation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the option `dimnames` which is part of the `matrix` function. The first part of `dimnames` are the row names, the second part the column names.

```
data.frame(matrix(c(1,2,3,4),nrow = 2, ncol = 2, dimnames = list(c("a","b"), c("c","d")))
```

The difference between `matrix(c(1,2,3,4),nrow = 2, ncol = 2, dimnames = list(c("a","b"), c("c","d")))` and the previous line is that the `matrix` call will give you a `matrix` with a `dimnnames` attribute. The `data.frame` line transforms the `matrix` into a `data.frame` with row names and column headers.

Answer (score 2):

We can use `setnames` and `row.names` to set them in one-line

```
setNames(data.frame(matrix(c(1,2,3,4),nrow=2,ncol=2), row.names=c("a","b")), c("c", "d"))

#  c d
#a 1 3
#b 2 4
```

Comment: are the answers of using `dimnames` and using the `setnames` .. `row.names` having the same end result?

Comment: @javadba, same result. `dimnames` is part of the `matrix` function. `setNames` is a separate function for setting names in a on / in a object.

Comment: @javadba, both solutions give the same result. I think the solution with ```dimnames()``` is a little easier to read, but both are nice solutions.